# Calculating on a cell that might change rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Pivot table, simplified version below. I'm taking B1 and B4 and calculating a percentage into B5. I'm new to excel.

=SUM(B1/B4) giving me 36%

[image]

I'm using the contents of B5 to display on another sheet with some other stats. However if more lines are added to my table and B4 becomes B5 my whole calculation is messed up. Is there a way to always track and use in the SUM of what was originally in B4.

Comment: A bit of a confusing question - but you may be able to use `INDEX/MATCH`?

Comment: Are you refering to an actual table? In that case growth does not matter. If you are not working with an actual table, you might want to refer to ranges using `INDEX`

Comment: @JvdV yes I'm using a Pivot Table

Comment: I was more refering to an actual table instead.

Comment: @JvdV ah sorry no it's a Pivot Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you can cheat:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH("Total",Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

We just look for the word *"Total"* and grab the value next to it.

*(change the worksheet name to match your setup)*

**EDIT#1:**

If you want the ***%*** value then:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH("Percentage",Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

Comment: @BigBen  ....................Thanks!............................

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but that wont work on my Total in the pivot table. It will work on other cells and totals but not in Pivot Table. I get N/A

Comment: @ultrarun  ***N/A*** means that `MATCH()` failed ...................make sure its not *Grand Total* instead of *Total* and make sure the cell with *Total* does not also contain any leading or trailing blanks.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly it, I'm now up and running!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, it may be better to use the `GETPIVOTDATA` function for work with the Pivot table:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Value",$A$1,"Name","val1")/GETPIVOTDATA("Value",$A$1)
```

[image]

Comment: The solution below worked for me but now I know about GETPIVOTDATA, thanks!